# Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Operation timed out

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I am trying to use Google Analytics API.  After I enabled Analytic API I received my client_secrets.p12 and downloaded the API client library.  I then replaced the `service_account_email` and changed the `key_file_location`. How ever when I run my script `'HelloAnalytics.php'`, I get an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with
>   message 'Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Operation
>   timed out' in
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Curl.php:115

Stack trace:

> 0
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php(136):
>   Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request)) 1
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(342):
>   Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request)) 2
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php(314):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array) 3
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/HelloAnalytics.php(30):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenWithAssertion(Object(Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials))
>   4 /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/HelloAnalytics.php(105):
>   getService() 5 {main}   thrown in
>   /Users/weiqi.tan/Downloads/ga_api/google-api-php-client/src/Google/IO/Curl.php
>   on line 115

I don't know if anyone else ever had the same problem. Please tell me why this happened and how to solve it.

Comment: 1. Can you `ping accounts.google.com`? 2. Can you `telnet accounts.google.com 443` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today so

I just disable the firewall and it worked for me

I am using avg internet security